# Python 2 to 3 Migration Process - Differences Regarding Unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x

I'm trying to migrate my code from Python2 to Python3 since Python2 is no longer supported.
However I'm having difficulties with the migration process because of the differences between the two versions. 
I know that Python2 used to have both string and unicode objects, while Python3 default storing of strings is unicode.

Somewhere in my code, I store a hexdigest representation of a tuple in a database.
I get this tuple from a user-filled form, and one of the values is of type unicode.
Since Python3 does not have the distinction between string and unicode, 
I've ended up with a different hexdigest representation of the tuple containing the same values.

Here is a code snippet showing my issue:

***Python2*** -

```py
In [1]: from hashlib import sha1

In [2]: cred = ('user', 'pass')

In [3]: sha1(str(cred)).hexdigest()
Out[3]: '7cd99ee437e8166559f55a0336d4b48d9bc62bb2'

In [4]: unicode_cred = ('user', u'pass')

In [5]: sha1(str(unicode_cred)).hexdigest()
Out[5]: '807a138ff9b0dd6ce6a937e3df3bba3223b40fcd'
```

***Python3*** -

```py
In [1]: from hashlib import sha1                                                

In [2]: cred = ('user', 'pass')                                                 

In [3]: sha1(str(cred)).hexdigest()                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-847e91fdf4c5> in <module>
----> 1 sha1(str(cred)).hexdigest()

TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

In [4]: sha1(str(cred).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()                             
Out[4]: '7cd99ee437e8166559f55a0336d4b48d9bc62bb2'

In [5]: unicode_cred = ('user', u'pass')                                        

In [6]: sha1(str(unicode_cred).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()                     
Out[6]: '7cd99ee437e8166559f55a0336d4b48d9bc62bb2'
```

As you can see, in Python2 `Out[3]` has a different value compared to `Out[5]`, 
while in Python3 `Out[4]` and `Out[6]` are the same.

***Is there a way to reproduce the value of `Out[5]` as shown in the Python2 snippet?***
As part of the migration process, I need to make sure the same input produces the same output, 
so I won't insert a new record to my database instead of update an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a hex digest of `str()` output is the problem.  `str()` is a version-dependent string and you need the exact same representation to form the hex digest:

Python 2

```
>>> unicode_cred = ('user', u'pass')
>>> str(unicode_cred)
"('user', u'pass')"
```

Python 3 (note the missing 'u'). The output of `str()` is also a Unicode string on Python 3, so it must be encoded to bytes to use with `sha1()`.  The `b` is not part of the string, but just denotes it is now a byte string.

```
>>> unicode_cred = ('user', u'pass')
>>> str(unicode_cred).encode('utf-8')
b"('user', 'pass')"
```

You'll need to form the same string with the `u` to get the same digest, and it is a bit ugly.  Here I use an f-string to custom format the tuple with a `u`.  I also encode with `ascii` since non-ASCII characters will create an additional issue.  Hopefully you don't have user names and passwords with non-ASCII.

```
>>> from hashlib import sha1
>>> unicode_cred = ('user', u'pass')
>>> f"('{unicode_cred[0]}', u'{unicode_cred[1]}')"
"('user', u'pass')"
>>> sha1(f"('{unicode_cred[0]}', u'{unicode_cred[1]}')".encode('ascii')).hexdigest()
'807a138ff9b0dd6ce6a937e3df3bba3223b40fcd'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Indeed a helpful one. However, this answer assumed I know in advance which string is unicode and which isn't. What do I do in other cases in which I don't necessarily know that? Is there a way to add this "u" in the beginning of a string other than the specific formatting you've offered?

Comment: @Matan No it wasn't a good choice to use `str()` for the hex digest.  That representation is version-dependent. A serializable, reproducible byte string (see `pickle` or `json` module) would be better, but if you need backward-compatibility you might be stuck with hacks like this.